# htaccess to redirect multiple different ID's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below and it works to redirect but there's loads of different ID's for the reviews.php file, is it possible for it to redirect all the id's from 1 to 10000?

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^item_id=3105$

RewriteRule ^reviews.php$ /? [R=302,L]

Thanks

Craig

Comment: Can you provide an example of the original url and the url you want to redirect to.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. Any reason you're using a 302 instead of a 301?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)item_id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^reviews.php$ /?item=%2 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Regarding 301 vs 302, because of search engines you should do a 302 redirect until you are sure everything is right, then switch to a 301.